# Time Based PHP Text

Tags: php, text, time

I've a quick question.  I have a call button on my site, and if possible I'd like to have a different phone number with PHP at different times.

Between 9am - 5pm, I'd like our local office number and between 5pm - 9am the next day, I'd like our 24 hour number.

Here's the current specific code in the header. It's using a Wordpress theme to call the call option, and the idea is to overwrite that with hard data. And here's the [website in question](http://asprayni.com).

With help from Iscariot, I have this code so far, but it's not quite working - the time is now 11am and it should be showing my first number (02840...) but it's not?  I've even tried 1am to 11pm, but it will not kick in the first number.

```
<span class="call-us-button">
  <?php if($hour > 1 && $hour < 23){
    echo '' . do_shortcode('[button link="tel:02840-631-245"]<span class="call-button-inner"><i class="call-us-icon"></i>CALL 02840 631 245</span>[/button]'); } else {
    echo '' . do_shortcode('[button link="tel:0800-077-6704"]<span class="call-button-inner"><i class="call-us-icon"></i>CALL 0800 077 6704</span>[/button]'); }
  ?></span>
```

I'd really appreciate any advice or pointers if you have any!

Thanks in advance,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

```
$hour = date('G', time()); 

if($hour > 8 && $hour < 18){
     // Phone Number
     echo '' . do_shortcode('[button link="' . get_prime_options('call_button_url') . '"]<span class="call-button-inner"><i class="call-us-icon"></i>' . get_prime_options('call_button_text') . '</span>[/button]');
} else {
     // other number
     echo '' . do_shortcode('[button link="' . get_prime_options('call_button_url') . '"]<span class="call-button-inner"><i class="call-us-icon"></i>' . get_prime_options('call_button_text') . '</span>[/button]');
}
```

However you need to note that the functions get_prime_options('call_button_url') needs to be changed to something else, and you need to go into that file and add the other number for it.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct timezone. Some hosting providers have set their timezone to UTC or to some other zone than where you are physically located.

Comment: False: You are using server time, if the business is only open during server hours you do not want to change the phone number based off user location.

Comment: Incorrect: You *are* using server time, not the time where the business is located. If the server is using UTC and the company is in Hawaii, you will need to check to make sure that `$hour` is not 8, but 20. Have you lost touch with reality?

Comment: thanks Iscariot, L0j1k, Fluffeh - much appreciated.  With this statement, would I be using within the above php file?  Where would I insert?  Sorry for the question if it's basic, I'm still relatively new to all this!

Comment: or should I be inserting twice - once into 'call button link' with links (the tel: URL) and once into the 'call button text' section?

Comment: Regardless of what Iscariot says, you DO need to make certain that the `$hour` value you test against is in fact the time you want the phone number to display during your open business hours. It will do you no good if `date('G', time());` returns 8 and displays your work phone number at 3am.

Comment: Ok thanks guys I will go try this now and report back with success.  I suppose I'll only know if it's a) broken or b) 5pm and it switches :)

Comment: Sorry Iscariot, if I want to just override the 'get_prime_options' sections can I just edit them to like this; if... // Phone number - echo '' . do_shortcode('[button link="tel:02890666666" .] etc - or will that be invalid?  I don't care about the prime options if I don't need them, they're just a theme fancy option box in WP admin!

Comment: I do not know what the code for get_prime_option looks like, I can not tell you for sure.  Test it, there is no harm in doing that.    I do not know what timezone you are at but you can change hour to whatever you want really quickly just to test and change it back.

Comment: ok sounds good, thanks Iscariot you're a legend! will report back findings!

Comment: Ah I encountered difficulty, as this is a responsive theme there is also a mobile call function, and the code I used broke the header. I think it's too difficult for me to achieve with current knowledge! Have updated the header above. I know the button shortcode is what I need, if I can scrap the get-prime-options I'd be half way there maybe?

Comment: You need to find "function get-prime-options ("

Comment: I think it's in functions.php, what would I need to do to it? I think it's used generically for all sorts of options - like backgrounds, text entry etc.

Comment: @Iscariot, I've tried to input your code above, but it's not quite there - have I used it correctly? It gave me $end error on header.php. I'm not sure if I inserted the $hour condition correctly?

Comment: $hour is just a variable.  Post the exact error it gives you.

Comment: sorry Iscariot, I tried it again with sheer concentration and it worked! I think I must have not closed a statement off properly. Legend - well happy with this! Thank you ever so much. Phil p.s. i will vote up when I get 15 rep.

Comment: @Iscariot I spoke too soon, the code works in terms of showing the correct button with links, but the number hasn't changed over and it's now in the 9-5 time zone here in UK. I've updated my code above - is there anything I'm missing out on? Many thanks, Phil

Comment: @Iscariot would you mind giving the edited code above the once over once you get a chance?  I can't get it to kick in for some reason, but it displays perfectly.

Comment: I don't have your code base,  like I said before you need to edit your functions or pay someone when you need them on the site that can do all that for you.  Ultimately, it's your business and you want to make sure its right 100% of the time to avoid customer lockouts.

Comment: Hey @Iscariot that's very true.  I have however ruled out the functions in above statement, and have tried various hours from 1 to 23, and now 0 to 24, but I just can't get the 02840 number to kick in. Thanks for the help so far anyway. I might ask another question with code above - is that allowed in stackOVerflow?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to get what you want - the `G` will return the current time in 24 hour time without leading zeroes.

```
if(date('G')>=9 && date('G') <= 17)
{
    // show normal phone Num
}
else
{
    // show after hours phone Num
}
```

Comment: This method unnecessarily calls the date function twice.  Using > and < is also superior to >= or <= in terms of processing time.

Comment: @Iscariot I don't think a `>=` on two integers will tear down the server :))